# UITextView undo manager do not work with replacement attributed string (iOS 6)

Tags: uitextview, ios6, nsundomanager

iOS 6 has been updated to use UITextView for rich text editing (a UITextView now earns an attributedText property —which is stupidly non mutable—). Here is a question asked on iOS 6 Apple forum under NDA, that can be made public since iOS 6 is now public...

In a UITextView, I can undo any font change but cannot undo a replacement in a copy of the view's attributed string. When using this code...

```
- (void) replace: (NSAttributedString*) old with: (NSAttributedString*) new

{
1.    [[myView.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] replace:new with:old];
2.    old=new;

}
```

... undoing is working well.

But if I add a line to get the result visible in my view, the undoManager do not fire the "replace:with:" method as it should...

```
- (void) replace: (NSAttributedString*) old with: (NSAttributedString*) new

{
1.    [[myView.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] replace:new with:old];
2.    old=new;
3.    myView.attributedText=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:old];

}
```

Any idea? I have the same problem with any of the replacement methods, using a range or not, for MutableAttributedString I tried to use on line "2"...

Answer (score 4):

Umm, wow I really didn't expect this to work! I couldn't find a solution so I just started trying anything and everything...

```
- (void)applyAttributesToSelection:(NSDictionary*)attributes {
    UITextView *textView = self.contentCell.textView;

    NSRange selectedRange = textView.selectedRange;
    UITextRange *selectedTextRange = textView.selectedTextRange;
    NSAttributedString *selectedText = [textView.textStorage attributedSubstringFromRange:selectedRange];

    [textView.undoManager beginUndoGrouping];
    [textView replaceRange:selectedTextRange withText:selectedText.string];
    [textView.textStorage addAttributes:attributes range:selectedRange];
    [textView.undoManager endUndoGrouping];

    [textView setTypingAttributes:attributes];
}
```

Comment: The most important thing is using `textView.replace...` instead of `textView.text.replace...` or `textView. textStorage.replace...`.

Answer (score 1):

`UITextView` has `undoManager` that will manage undo and redo for free without requiring any additional code.

Replacing its `attributedText` will reset the `undoManager` (Updating text and its attributes in `textStorage` not work for me either). However, I discovered that undo and redo functionality works normally when formatting text without replacing `attributedText` but by standard edit actions (Right click on highlighting text > Font > Bold (Mac Catalyst)).

To ensure that `undoManager` works properly, you need to use only certain specific methods of `UITextView`. Using other methods may break the undo functionality of `UITextView`.

**Editing Text**

1. You need to set the `allowsEditingTextAttributes` of `UITextView` to be `true`, this will make `UITextView` support undo and redo of `attributedText`.

```
self.textView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
```

2. If you want to change the text of `attributedText`, use `replace(_:withText:)` of `UITextInput`, or `insertText(_:)` and `deleteBackward()` of `UIKeyInput` that `UITextView` conforming to.

```
self.textView.replace(self.textView.selectedTextRange!, withText: "test")
```

**Updating Attributes**

If you want to change attributes of text, use `updateTextAttributes(conversionHandler:)` of `UITextView` instead.

```
self.textView.updateTextAttributes { _ in
                
    let font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: font,
    ]
    
    return attributes

}
```

or

```
self.textView.updateTextAttributes { attributes in
    
    let newAttributes = attributes
    let font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    let newAttributes: [.font] = font
    
    return newAttributes

}
```

**Inserting Attachments**

According to the documentation for `init(attachment:)` in `NSAttributedString`.

> This is a convenience method for creating an attributed string containing an attachment using `character` (NSTextAttachment.character) as the base character.

If you want to add an attachment using `updateTextAttributes`, you should insert a special character (The attachment will not show up if you are not using this character.) for the attachment first (`NSTextAttachment.character`).

For example,

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment(image: image)
let specialChar = String(Character(UnicodeScalar(NSTextAttachment.character)!))

textView.insertText(specialChar)
textView.selectedRange = NSRange(location: textView.selectedRange.lowerBound-specialChar.count, length: specialChar.count)
textView.updateTextAttributes { attributes in
           
    var newAttributes = attributes
    newAttributes[.attachment] = attachment
    return newAttributes
            
}
```

For changing text and its attributes in specific range, modify the `selectedRange` or `selectedTextRange` of `UITextView`.

To implement undo and redo buttons, check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50530040/8637708

I have tested with Mac Catalyst, it should work on iOS and iPadOS too.

Answer (score 0):

The Undo Manager is reset after setting its 'text' or 'attributedText' property, this is why it does not work. Whether this behavior is a bug or by design I don't know.

However, you can use the UITextInput protocol method instead.

- (void)replaceRange:(UITextRange *)range withText:(NSString *)text

This works.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that this protocol cannot replace an attributedString, only a NSString.